# Why do some sites have HTTPS?

Tags: https

Why do some sites have HTTPS?

I have a web application that I developed. Do I need HTTPS? If so, how can I install it? Is it free?

Comment: To say how you can activate https we should know In which language is written you site? and in which application server?

Comment: The language he used doesn't really matter.. just which webserver he's using.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From

[HTTP Secure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Secure)

> Hypertext Transfer Protocol Secure (HTTPS) is a combination of the
>   Hypertext Transfer Protocol with the
>   SSL/TLS protocol to provide encryption
>   and secure identification of the
>   server. HTTPS connections are often
>   used for payment transactions on the
>   World Wide Web and for sensitive
>   transactions in corporate information
>   systems.

***Do i need https?***

This entirely depends on the type of site that you are using. If you have sensitive data then use https.

***How can i install it?***

You have to get SSL certificates from a Cettificate Provide like [Thawte](http://www.thawte.com/), [Verisign](http://www.verisign.com/) etc and have to install the certificate in your application.

Comment: It's expensive because you are paying for the service of having Verisign or whoever actually verify your identity, and then use their own credentials to guarantee that you are who your certificate says you are. There are probably cheaper providers than Verisign and Thawte, but then again, the big expensive providers are trading on the fact that they can't afford damage to their reputation.

Answer (score 7):

HTTPS is representative of a secure connection, typically used when your dealing with shopping carts, credit card numbers, etc. To get set up, you'll need an SSL Certificate. You should speak with your host about this matter.

Comment: To generalise, any transaction of sensitive data should use this secure method of communication. :)

Answer (score 3):

HTTPS is HTTP over SSL (encrypted connection).

SSL certificates are free, getting them signed by a known Certificate Authority isn't free, nor cheap. Getting them signed means that the browser won't complain when a user will visit your site. Unsigned ones are as safe as the signed ones tho.

And you do need them if you ask for sensitive information from your users or if you give them sensitive info.

Answer (score 0):

HTTPS is a protocol for securing the information sent from the people using your website to your web server.

You only need it if you have them enter sensitive information such as credit cards, social security numbers, etc.

If you are not dealing with this type of information, you do not need it.

If you do need https because you have sensitive information being entered in your website, your web hosting company can help you set it up.  There is generally an additional cost involved.

Answer (score 0):

HTTPS is a combination of the Hypertext Transfer Protocol with the SSL/TLS protocol to provide encryption and secure identification of the server.
from wikipedia

Information/DATA passed through this protocol in encrypted

Answer (score 0):

https is the secure (meaning encrypted transfer of content both ways) version of html.

your application needs it, if you must be certain no one reads what is being send/received.

most web server support https, and your application might, depending on the libraries you used to communicate.